# How can I add matrices inside a cell array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have a (1xn) cell array A where each matrix is a 1000x1000.

Basically, I want to do A{1}+A{2}+A{3}+...+A{n}

I don't know the size of the array beforehand. So I should do a size(A) and add all the available matrices inside.

- I want to sum all of them using a loop
- But preferably in a vectorized way as I'll eventually add thousands of them and need the speed improvement.

---

How I store data into the cell array:

```
for k = 1:length(pcpFileNames)
    pcp{k} = imread(pcpFileNames{k}); %Read all pcp files
end

where 

pcpFileNames = 

    'PCPRATE.20110612.000000.tif'
    'PCPRATE.20110612.000500.tif'
    'PCPRATE.20110612.001000.tif'
    'PCPRATE.20110612.001500.tif'
    'PCPRATE.20110612.002000.tif'
    'PCPRATE.20110612.002500.tif'
    'PCPRATE.20110612.003000.tif'
    'PCPRATE.20110612.003500.tif'
    'PCPRATE.20110612.004000.tif'
    'PCPRATE.20110612.004500.tif'
```

---

**Proposed solution not working:**

```
pcpAccum = pcp{1};
for m = 2:numel(pcp)
    pcpAccum = pcpAccum + pcp{k};
end
```

This is giving me incorrect results. I checked one of the cells and it has zero value even though it should have 1.8 (example).

---

**Working solution**

```
%Create a multidimensional array to store the data

precip = zeros(3501,7001,length(pcpFileNames)); %Pre-allocating an array

for k = 1:length(precipFileNames)
    precip(:,:,k) = imread(precipFileNames{k}); %Read all files
end

pcpAccum = sum(pcp,3);
```

Comment: If your matrices are all the same size there is no need to use a cell array.

Comment: What is the recommended way to store it? Basically, I use the imread function to store equally-sized tif files into a cell array...

Comment: Matrices can have more than two dimensions: `A(:, :, n)`.

Comment: Thanks. I have added the code that I am using to add the matrices to an array. Never used more than a 2D matrix. Will look into it...

Comment: I would really appreciate it if you show me some example code for my use case.

Comment: See [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/sco1/037e914ed17e3d84c4d1)

Answer (score 1):

To add them in a vectorized way:

```
B = sum(cat(3,A{:}),3);
```

However, adding a lot of matrices like above way is a *very* bad idea if your matrices are already big. Your 2D matrices are already in memory; to create the 3D matrix that will vectorize your addition will consume *once again* that amount of memory, but now in a *contiguous memory area*. Due to memory fragmentation is quite likely that you'll have the *total* amount of memory to do the vectorized sum, but not in a *contiguous area of memory*; so your program will fail needlessly.

What I would recommend in this case is a nice well-behaved loop:

```
B = A{1};
for k = 2:numel(A)
        B = B + A{k};
end;
```

However, the loop has its own issues, and the speed is not one. The thing is that accumulating in an ever growing manner might give you precision errors (for floating point types) or integer overflows (for integer types).

To overcome the overflow errors caused by an integer type returned by `imread`, convert the data to a wider type (`double` is the best bet):

```
B = double(A{1});
for k = 2:numel(A)
        B = B + double(A{k});
end;
```

Comment: I am not getting correct results using this. Probably precision errors. Not sure how to fix this.

Comment: The first response is giving me a correct result. But as you said, speed is constrained.

Comment: @maximusdooku the incorrect results may be caused by overflows due to the integer type (i bet `imread` returns some `int<n>` or `uint<n>` types). One idea would be to convert the matrices to a wider type. I'll edit my response for this eventuality; please let me know if it does the trick for you.

Comment: I imported one file separately using imread, and this is what I get: Name  f       Size 3501x7001 Bytes 98042004 Class single  Attributes

Comment: @maximusdooku the post was edited. Again, let me know if it does the trick.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work. The summed value for a particular cell is still 0 instead of 1.8. I get 1.8 from your first answer. And I checked manually too.

Comment: @maximusdooku could you tell me what gives you `class(pcp{1})`? I used the variable name suggested by your post. Also, what you posted is kinda tricky: The size is assumed 1000x1000, right? but the numbers from the `import` say 3501x7001. is this okay?

Comment: class(pcp{1}) = ans = single.     This is what I get

Comment: Or do you think I should go this route (given in question comments)?:https://gist.github.com/sco1/037e914ed17e3d84c4d1

Comment: @maximusdooku When you say "the summed value for a particular cell", do you mean "the summed value for a particular pixel"? because I'm not trying to sum up all the pixels in an image, I'm trying to sum up same pixels in different images. And, yeah, the Gist example prevents you wasting 2 times the memory required by storing the pics, by saving them directly in an array that can be summed up in a vectorized manner; you should try that.

Comment: Yes, I should have been more precise. I meant pixel-by-pixel addition. I don't need the sum of all pixels in one image.

Comment: @maximusdooku any progress on the issue? :-)

Comment: Yes. I stored it in a 3D array and it works now. Will post my answer.

Comment: I have added it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @maximusdooku Okay. As soon as you post your answer I will delete mine, since is useless. If I may recommend something: please ask `excaza` first to post an answer, so you can credit him with the answer (if it's his). Sometimes is important. :-)

Comment: Thank you. You can leave the answer. It's a good discussion and would help others in avoiding pitfalls.

Comment: @maximusdooku Glad that I could help somehow. :-)